# How to display each month on X Axis using Charts (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I trying to use Charts, but i can't display each month on X axis, only through one. Look at [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZI0I.png).

In `stringForValue` i tried to print value and it's show : `0 2 4 6 8 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 2 4 6 8 10` But why it's passed three time which first and last time through one? What can i do for displaying each month?

```
import UIKit

import Charts

class BarChartViewController: UIViewController {

    var months = [String]()
    var unitsSold = [Double]()

    weak var axisFormatDelegate: IAxisValueFormatter?

    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        axisFormatDelegate = self

        months = ["Jan",
                  "Feb",
                  "Mar",
                  "Apr",
                  "May",
                  "Jun",
                  "Jul",
                  "Aug",
                  "Sep",
                  "Oct",
                  "Nov",
                  "Dec"
        ]

        unitsSold = [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0]

        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)


    }

    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        barChartView.noDataText = "NO DATA"

        var dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: dataPoints)

            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

        barChartView.data = chartData

        barChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
    }


}

extension BarChartViewController: IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        print(Int(value))

        return months[Int(value)]
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options to solve your problem.

Just set property `labelCount` for xAxis, e.g. `barChartView.xAxis.labelCount = 12`.

Or user method `setLabelCount(:)`, e.g. `barChartView.xAxis.setLabelCount(12, force: true)`.

Pay your attention that using property `labelCount` does not guarantee that the number of labels will exactly equal to specified by you.